# Error al enviar parámetro desde React js a Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Tengo una duda acerca de como enviar un parámetro desde un componente desde `React Js` a `Node`.

En mi componente esta la siguiente función, la cual al hacer `click` en un botón captura el valor de un `input`, lo concadena a una variable predefinida de la api de **Google Maps**, y me retorna unos valores.

Pero quiero poder realizar dicho procedimiento del lado del servidor y no del cliente.

Trato de hacer una prueba sencilla, y me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

#### Funcion del lado del cliente

```
<button onClick={this.mostrarMensaje}>Mensaje</button>

mostrarMensaje(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const fullAddress = this.state.address;
        respuestaMensaje(fullAddress);
 }
```

#### Fichero lado del servidor

```
export function respuestaMensaje(fullAdress) {
    console.log(fullAdress);
}
```

Lo que deseo es enviar lo que esta en `this.state.address`, y realizar toda esta operación de enviar la información y recibir del lado del servidor.

Comment: Quieres un servicio en node que llame a un servicio externo?

Comment: Es un poco más complejo lo que querés hacer, depende de varios factores como para hacerlo, depende de tus dependencias pero prácticamente tenés que generar dos index.

Comment: @JackNavaRow exactamente eso quiero :D

Answer (score 2):

Pude encontrar el error luego de buscar y revisar bien, hacia falta el `bind()`, luego de la función en el botón para mostrar el mensaje.

#### Solución

`<button onClick={this.mostrarMensaje.bind(this)}>Mensaje</button>`